# Generate Istio metrics based on URL paths

Tags: istio

I use istio service mesh version 1.5.6 to handle my following API traffic,

```
GET test.com/hello

GET test.com/hellofails
```

I wanted to get metrics like 2XX, 5XX counts based on the URL paths like /hello and /hellofails. Prometheus server is running in istio-system namespace to collect metrics from istio. What istio provides by default is the collective metrics of 2XX and 5XX count on test.com. I have tried to inject the sidecar proxy in the IstioIngress-gateway-pods running in the control plane, thinking that they will expose URL path based metrics. But I couldn't inject sidecars in the control plane. Is there a way to collect metrics based on API paths using istio?

Any help will be much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Istio 1.6 introduces more customization of metrics, but as far as I know you cannot do that with 1.5

Check out this page, I think this is exactly what you want: https://istio.io/latest/docs/tasks/observability/metrics/classify-metrics/

Basically, it consists in defining an EnvoyFilter resource that will insert some custom labels in the metrics based on conditions run per request.

Comment: Hey @Joel, followed above doc, but it is not giving request_operation value when I try to hit service using Ingress gateway. It only gives value when I hit it using some other pod. Any idea, how to achieve this?